# Java - How can I parse multiple JSON objects in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, filereader

I'm trying to parse multiple objects from a REST response. They initially get returned as JSON Lines (jsonl file format). i.e.:

```
{"AccountId":"123","Name":"Jeff"}
{"AccountId":"456","Name":"Joe"}
{"AccountId":"789","Name":"John"}
```

The first thing I do is convert it to a string:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.com", 8080));
    HttpsURLConnection httpsCon = (HttpsURLConnection) (new URL(url)).openConnection(proxy);
    InputStream inputStream = httpsCon.getInputStream();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    char[] arr = new char[8 * 1024];
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    int numCharsRead;
    while ((numCharsRead = reader.read(arr, 0, arr.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.append(arr, 0, numCharsRead);
    }
    reader.close();
    return buffer.toString();
```

But I get errors trying to parse the String it as it's not JSON structure. So I've used a regex to format the objects into JSON structure.

```
{"AccountId":"123","Name":"Jeff"},{"AccountId":"456","Name":"Joe"},{"AccountId":"789","Name":"John"}
```

What I've tried so far:

```
JSONArray dataArr = new JSONArray(newTargetString);
```

Results in: type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

```
JSONObject dataObj = new JSONObject(newTargetString);
```

Results in a single object getting parsed instead of all 3.

Comment: `JSONArray` should look like: `[{"valid json obj"}, {...}, ...]`, a (wrapping) `JSONObject` like `{...}`

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. I'm trying to figure out the best way to parse the above String as a valid JSONObject or JSONArray

Comment: by doing: `JSONArray dataArr = new JSONArray("["+newTargetString+"]");` ...

Comment: ..resp.: `JSONObject dataObj = new JSONObject("{"+newTargetString+"}");` !?

Comment: @xerx593 This will work. Thank you. Are you aware of any way to parse json lines directly without needing to manipulate the String to add the square brackets and replace \n with commas? Regardless, your initial solution answers my question so if you want to type it in as the answer I'll give it a check mark. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! (it is not clean, but "quick fix underlying error" solution), advanced: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming ! ;)

Comment: some options with jackson: https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/line-delimited-json-with-jackson-69c9e4cb6c00